# ng-select in Angular5 issue : ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at NgDropdownPanelComponent.ngOnInit (ng-select.js

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular5, angular2-template

I'm working with ng-select 2.0.0 in my project angular5 as in  [this link](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources)
, i can get results from the api rest spring boot but i'm fascing a problem i get this error while i click on ng-select :

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at NgDropdownPanelComponent.ngOnInit (ng-select.js:1450)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12352)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13876)
```

and also i can't select the information ( in this case attribute 'nom') i want , it's like the ng select is blocked or somthing like this .

this is my code for project.component.html

```
<ng-select  *ngIf="_listClients"
             [items]="listClient"
              bindLabel ="nom"
              bindValue ="id"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId">

</ng-select>

<p>
  Selected city ID: {{selectedPersonId | json}}
</p>
```

This is the file project.component.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ProjetService} from '../../../../../service/projet.service';
import {Projet} from '../../Models/Projet';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {ClientService} from '../../../../../service/client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedPersonId:number = null;
  _listClients :any;


constructor(private router:Router,
              private projetSevice:ProjetService,
              private clientServ:ClientService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

       this.clientList();
  }


get listClient() {
     return this._listClients ? this._listClients.map(item => {
      return {id: item.id, prenom : item.prenom , nom : item.nom}
    }) : [];
  }


  clientList(){

     this.clientServ.getListClients()
       .subscribe((data:any)=>{
        this._listClients=data;
       },err=>{
         console.log('this is error ');
       })

  }

}
```

Any help ?

Comment: Are you using ng-select 2.0.0?

Comment: Yes i'm using ng-select 2.0.0

Comment: I think, this version has issue. I found 2 issue request in the GitHub repo.  Try to downgrade the version to v1.4.1. `npm uninstall @ng-select/ng-select` them `npm i -s @ng-select/ng-select@1.4.1`

Comment: Thank you for your help , this fixed my issue and saved my time !!

Comment: with pleasur ,i have only one problem  i can't use the scrollbar it's not working , should i add somthing to make it working ?

Comment: You meant scrollbar in drop-down menu (using ng-select). Right ? I don't see any issue regarding `scrollbar`.  Feel free to open a new Question.

Comment: yes this is what i mean , okey i'll open a new Question about this , thank you again .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(Just copy pasting the answer from my comment to close the question)

I think,`ng-select v2.0.0` has this issue. I found 2 issue request in the GitHub repo.

#### Workaround:

Try to downgrade the version to v1.4.1.

```
npm uninstall @ng-select/ng-select 
npm i -s @ng-select/ng-select@1.4.1
```

---

#### EDIT: (25.05.18)

There issue is for breaking changes from `Rxjs 6.0`. If you're using `Angular v5` install `ng-select v1.x` or install `ng-select v2.0+` with `rxjs-compat`.

```
npm i -s @ng-select/ng-select@1.x
//or
npm i -s @ng-select/ng-select@latest rxjs-compat
```

Comment: I downgraded the version to v1.4.1 and it worked well ^^

Comment: "npm i -s @ng-select/ng-select@latest rxjs-compat" not working. Downgrade works ;)

Answer (score 3):

As stated on in the readme of the repo https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#v200:

> Latest version targets Angular v6 since it uses new RxJS which has
>   breaking changes. If you are using Angular v5 you could use ng-select
>   v1.x or install rxjs-compat compatability package. We will support
>   v1.x with latest bug fixes to allow easier migration. For v1.x you can
>   refer the 1.x branch.

However using v2.0.0 with rxjs-compat didn't work for me. I am using Angular v5.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the ng-select version you have install for the respective Angular.x

1. if >=13.0.0 <14.0.0 - ng-select version should be v8.x
2. if >=12.0.0 <13.0.0 - ng-select version should be v7.x
3. if >=11.0.0 <12.0.0 - ng-select version should be v6.x
4. if >=10.0.0 <11.0.0 - ng-select version should be v5.x
5. if >=9.0.0 <10.0.0  - ng-select version should be v4.x
6. if >=8.0.0 <9.0.0    - ng-select version should be v3.x
7. if >=6.0.0 <8.0.0    - ng-select version should be v2.x
8. if v5.x.x   - ng-select version should be v1.x